# AJAX - Unable to get property of 'innerHTML of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xml

I am using AJAX to return XML. When testing on IE, I am getting the following error:

> Unable to get property of 'innerHTML' of undefined or null reference

The error is occurring  here: `var ajax_html = xml.getElementById("search-ajax-content").innerHTML;`

Has anyone seen this error before? Should I be waiting somehow for this element to load? Looks like ajax_html is returning `null` for IE... Any help is appreciated!

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/search-ajax/" + window.location.search + "&pagination=" + page,
    dataType:"xml",
    contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    error: function() {
        // TODO: handle errors
    },
    success: availability_response
});

function availability_response(data) {
    var xml = data;

    $("#wait-element-container").remove();
    var ajax_html = xml.getElementById("search-ajax-content").innerHTML; // error occurs here
    $("#postload-target").append(ajax_html);
}
```

Comment: If the `"search-ajax-content"` element is within that data response, then yes, it haven't been loaded yet

Comment: `contentType:'xml'` can be left off in this snippet.  You are not sending any data to the endpoint at all, other than the pagination parameter

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(data)` yet, to make sure you can actually call `getElementById()` on it? - edit: @Taplar I'm guessing you mean `contentType`?

Comment: You may have to derefence it, try xml.getElementById("search-ajax-content")[0].innerHTML

Comment: @BernardWei `getElementById` only returns a single element, as reflected by the method name and how ids work.